# Smooth looking at target disables rotation around another axis

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a problem with rotating a 3d object. Its a lock-on rocket, that is supposed to be always facing towards its target but also should be spinning around its x axis.

I am using following code to make it smoothly look at target:

```
void SmoothLookAt (Vector3 target)
{
    Vector3 difference = target - transform.position;
    float rotationZ = Mathf.Atan2(difference.y, difference.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    var targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, rotationZ);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, 5 * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

How can I also make it spin around x axis?

I've tried to add

```
transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * speed);
```

but its no luck. my rocket refuses to spin at all (facing forward works as intended)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have two different functions writing the rotation. One that expects it to not change from its own last alteration and one that forces it to a specific orientation. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: i've just said that Rotate() didint work, and its there for clarification what i want to chieve

Comment: You need to use transform hierarchies, you can't just smash two rotate functions together and expect them to work.

Comment: @Draco18s Yes, that worked. If you will post this as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use multiple transforms

As you have two competing types of rotation, the only way to get them to stack is to assign each one to a transform in a transform hierarchy.  Make the "spin" part a child of the "look towards the target" part.  The transform matrices that underlay the scene hierarchy will take care of the rest for you.